# boost mutex, condition, scoped_lock , am I using them wrong here?

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void PushMessage(MyMessage m) // Thread 1 calls this
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
        mQueue.push_back(m);
        mCondition.notify_one();
    }

    MyMessage PopMessage()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
        while(mQueue.empty())
            mCondition.wait(lock);

        MyMessage message = mQueue.front();
        mQueue.pop_front();
        return message;
    }

    void foo() // thread 2 is running this loop, and supposed to get messages
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            MyMessage message = PopMessage();

            do_something(message);
        }
    }
private:
    std::deque<MyMessage> mQueue;

    boost::mutex mMutex;
    boost::condition mCondition;
};
```

When I run the code, `PushMessage` is called, and `foo()` is waiting on `PopMessage()`, but `PopMessage` never returns.

What does `do_something` here is not irrelevant I think.

What am I doing wrong here?
Strangely, the above code worked fine under mac, but I'm having trouble on linux.
boost version is 1.44.0

Thank you

Comment: What is `do_something`? Who calls `PushMessage`? This code is incomplete at best.

Comment: There is no `boost::condition` in thread library. Did you mean `boost::condition_variable`? As written, and with that fix, your code runs on linux with boost 1.42 and boost 1.46 (don't have 1.44 at hand) and does not show the problems you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than letting the scope of the lock object expire before it unlocks, you could try to manually unlock the mutex in `PushMessage()` before you unblock the waiting thread, i.e.,

```
void PushMessage(MyMessage m) // Thread 1 calls this
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
    mQueue.push_back(m);

    lock.unlock(); // <== manually unlock

    mCondition.notify_one();
}
```

That way when thread 2 unblocks, there will be no "cross-over" time where thread 1 contains the lock, and thread 2 is trying to obtain a lock on your mutex.  I don't see why that would create problems, but again, at least you won't have thread 2 trying to call `lock.lock()` while thread 1 still contains the lock.

Comment: I recently learnt this is actually more complicated than it seems, here is the link:
http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/condvars-signal-with-mutex-locked-or-not/
there is such a thing that `wait morphing` optimization, which prevents the problem you talk about. And notifying while locked will make the overall program safer when using more than 2 threads.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need 2 mutex objects, one is for synchronizing method call in different threads, one is for condition wait. You mixed them.

Comment: I do not think it is correct. The mutex should protect both signal/wait and condition set/condition check. The condition in this case is `mQueue.empty()`, thus the queue should be protected by this same mutex.